# If ${X_n} < \infty$, then $\sup {X_n} < \infty$, True or False?

Tags: real-analysis

This maybe very bad but please correct me. Given $X_n >0$.

Suppose ${X_n} < \infty$, then $\max{X_n} + 1 < \infty$.

This means $\max{X_n} + 1$ is a upper bound of ${X_n}$.

Thus, $\sup {X_n} \le \max{X_n} + 1 < \infty$

Why is this wrong? or right?

Comment: What range does $n$ live in?

Comment: If there are infinitely many $n$, then $\max x_n$ may not exist. Consider $x_n = n$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $X_n < \infty$ is a bit sloppy, because if it is read literally, it holds for a specific value $X_n$, even if the use of subscript would suggest that $X_n$ is part of a sequence of values.  If we then talk about $\sup X_n$, then the context of a sequence is made clear, but it still doesn't imply that all of the terms of the sequence are bounded above.  For that, you need to explicitly state something like $$\forall n, \quad X_n < \infty,$$ or $$X_n < \infty, \quad n = 1, 2, \ldots.$$  If this is the intended meaning, then the counterexample $X_n = n$ suffices, since for each $n = 1, 2, \ldots$, it is true that $n < \infty$, yet $\sup n = \infty$.  The statement $$\forall n, \quad X_n < \infty$$ is **not** equivalent to saying $$\exists C < \infty \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \forall n, \quad X_n < C.$$  The reason why is because if one wanted to say the second statement, one would not have written $X_n < \infty$ in the first place.  One would have simply written $X_n < C$.

Answer (score -1):

To say that $X_n < \infty$ means that there exists a (finite) number $C$ such that $$\forall\, n\ ,\quad X_{n}<C\ ;$$ in other words the number $C$ is *an* upper bound for the sequence $X_n\ .$ Since $\sup X_n$ is the *smallest* upper bound for the sequence, the number $\sup X_n$ cannot be greater than the upper bound $C\ ,$ hence $$\sup X_n \leq C\ .$$

Comment: $X_n < \infty$ only means $X_n$ are finite, but they are not necessarily bounded. Your constant $C$ may depend on the index $n$.

Comment: Actually, the notation $X_n<\infty$ is quite ambiguous. You interpreted it in a *uniform* way, but to me it looks more like *pointwise*: $\forall n, \exists C : X_n<C$, which would not imply the boundedness of the supremum.